# How to pivot in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a list of Student_IDs that belong to multiple Credit Groups.
I'm trying to structure them in a clear way for analysis. I want to have one record for each student and their Group information in columns with an YES/NO flag as the column value.

I'm currently only able to structure using the below query in a format that generates a separate record for each Group:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, 
CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01') THEN 'YES' END AS GROUP1,
CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20') THEN 'YES' END AS GROUP2,
CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00') THEN 'YES' END AS  GROUP3
FROM STUDENT_TABLE 
WHERE CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01', '0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20', '1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00')
ORDER BY STUDENT_ID;
```

Output:

```
STUDENT_ID  GROUP1  GROUP2  GROUP3
1233        YES     null    null
1233        null    YES     null
3456        YES     null    null
3456        null    null    YES
2376        YES     null    null
2376        null    YES     null
3499        YES     null    null
3499        null    YES     null
3499        null    null    YES
```

And what I want it to look like is:

```
STUDENT_ID  GROUP1  GROUP2  GROUP3
1233        YES     YES     null
3456        YES     null    YES
2376        YES     YES     null
3499        YES     YES     YES
```

How to achieve this in oracle SQL? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aggregating by `STUDENT_ID`, and then taking the `MAX` of your `CASE` expressions to rollup the results into what you want.

```
SELECT
    STUDENT_ID, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01') THEN 'YES' END) AS GROUP1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20') THEN 'YES' END) AS GROUP2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00') THEN 'YES' END) AS GROUP3
FROM STUDENT_TABLE 
WHERE
    CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01', '0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20', '1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00')
GROUP BY
    STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY
    STUDENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also achieve by using nvl and group by in making it as subquery:-

**Used dummy table :-**

```
     with dummy_table as (   
        select  1233  as  "STUDENT_ID",     'YES'as  "GROUP1",   null as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 1233  as  "STUDENT_ID",     null as  "GROUP1",  'YES' as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 3456  as  "STUDENT_ID",     'YES'as  "GROUP1",   null as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 3456  as  "STUDENT_ID",     null as  "GROUP1",  null  as  "GROUP2",  'YES'as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
       select  2376  as  "STUDENT_ID",     'YES'as  "GROUP1",   null as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 2376  as  "STUDENT_ID",     null as  "GROUP1",  'YES' as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 3499  as  "STUDENT_ID",     'YES'as  "GROUP1",   null as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 3499  as  "STUDENT_ID",     null as  "GROUP1",  'YES' as  "GROUP2",  null as   "GROUP3" from dual union all
        select 3499  as  "STUDENT_ID",     null as  "GROUP1",  null  as  "GROUP2", 'YES' as   "GROUP3" from dual)
        select STUDENT_ID, nvl(GROUP1, 'YES') ,nvl(GROUP2, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP3, 'YES') from dummy_table group by STUDENT_ID,nvl(GROUP1, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP2, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP3, 'YES')
```

**By using actual table**

```
        with stud_table as ( 
                SELECT STUDENT_ID, 
                CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01') THEN 'YES' END AS GROUP1,
                CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20') THEN 'YES' END AS GROUP2,
                CASE WHEN CREDIT_ID IN ('1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00') THEN 'YES' END AS  GROUP3
                FROM STUDENT_TABLE 
                WHERE CREDIT_ID IN ('1000.00',  '0105.00', '0707.00','8009.00', '0809.01', '0987.00', '0125.00', '1055.00', '0890.00', '6600.20', '1100.00', '1190.01', '0045.20', '0675.00') )
        select STUDENT_ID, nvl(GROUP1, 'YES') ,nvl(GROUP2, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP3, 'YES') 
          from dummy_table 
         group by STUDENT_ID,nvl(GROUP1, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP2, 'YES'),nvl(GROUP3, 'YES')
         order by STUDENT_ID;
```